# Where should we define the properties

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have imported an Existing Application into Eclipse Helios Version.
I am  using Tomcat 6.0 server.
Inside our code we have this:

```
instanceName = System.getProperty("tata.instanceName");
systemPath = System.getProperty("tata.home");
```

Please tell me where should I define this properties? (SO that it reads this values from our environemnt)

For your information, I would be developing application inside the Windows and deploy it into Remote Linux server .

Answer (score 0):

- in eclipse, double-click the server, "Open launch configuration", go to "Arguments" tab, and add the properies.
- outside of eclipse, add them to JAVA_OPTS in `catalina.bat` / `catalina.sh`

The format of the properties is:

```
-Dtata.instanceName=foo -Dtata.home=bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it as part of the java command by specifing the `-Dkey=value` pairs or do it programmatically.

```
java com.foo.Bar -Dtata.instanceName=baz
```

or

```
System.setProperty("tata.instanceName", "baz");
```

Comment: when it's a server, it's a bit more special (not the mechanics, but the place where the properties are set)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `-D` flags when running Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

On the command line you can do

```
-Dtata.instanceName=name -Dtata.home=home
```

Answer (score 0):

Add lines like this to $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/setenv.sh

```
export JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dpropname=value "
```

Comment: Thanks , Whether this should be like this ??                                  export JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dpropname=tata.home="/Test/Myproperties.properties""  .

Comment: @yyyi777 No it should be `-Dtata.home=/Test/Myproperties.properties` sorry I tried to make the answer a bit generic.

Comment: You find official documentation here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html